# Alphabet Drawing App

Tags: android, canvas

I m making an app for drawing alphabets and letters for kids where i need to draw the alphabets with dotted strokes/line inside the alphabets. I cant find any tutorial or library for the same. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Not the right place to ask for libraries that do this or that. Have a look here for things to keep in mind while asking questions on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

setpath effect on the paint object:-

```
Paint fgPaintSel = new Paint();
fgPaintSel.setARGB(255, 0, 0,0);
fgPaintSel.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
fgPaintSel.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,20}, 0));
```

you can create all sorts of dotted patterns by supplying more numbers in the int[] array it specifies the ratios of dash and gap. This is a simple, equally dashed, line.

draw text on canvas:-

```
canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, fgPaintSel);
```